# Merge Replication could not drop object due to Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-replication, merge-replication

Good Day Everyone.

I am slightly confused here. (it doesn't take a lot to confuse me though)

I have a merge replication and it started giving me this error:

> Could not drop object 'TableName' because it is referenced by a
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 3726)

I understand why I m getting the error: it is trying to drop the table that is referenced in another table as a foreign constraint, what I am battling to understand is why it is trying to drop the table?

I have deleted the foreign key reference an the subscriber, the replication goes through only once and as soon as the process repeats I am stuck with this error again.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Have there been any issues with the replication? The only time this actually should happen at all is when initiating a new snapshot.

Comment: We had connectivity issues on one subscriber connection, but I have multiple replications running and this is  now happening on all the instances. I do not want to reinitialize as we are running very low bandwidth links and it takes days to finalize the process.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the foreign key constraints in the subscription and publisher.

Not ideal, but it works for now.